# Converting an AS3 game to HTML5 - latest method?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, html5-canvas

I know this question has been asked before but the ones that I have seen are from years ago. I would like to convert an old AS3 game to HTML5.

Is there a more up to date method of doing this? What tools are being used to do this?

Comment: ruffle is the one to watch - but its not done yet: https://github.com/ruffle-rs/ruffle
there is shumway which was discontinued but might be your best bet: https://github.com/mozilla/shumway

Comment: Thank you @Zevan , I got it working on Shumway after a while of configuring and reading the docs.